# Create a Rule to ingest Cloudtrail metrics for Secrets Manager whenever a secret is retrieved

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms, aws-event-bridge

I have created a cloudtrail for my secrets manager to actively monitor whenever a user retrieves a secret.

I can see that it is working in cloudtrail via the bottom snippet.
[image]

I have configured my cloudtrail as below.
[image]

I have created a rule in eventbridge to essentially accept everything
[image]

But i am not getting any events when i am retrieving a secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-aws-service-specific-topics.html#cloudtrail-aws-service-specific-topics-eventbridge)

> Events from API actions that start with the keywords List, Get, or Describe are not processed by EventBridge, with the exception of events from the following STS actions: GetFederationToken and GetSessionToken.

As a result, EventBridge won't process **GetSecretValue** events as it starts with the keyword `Get`.

---

However, whenever someone tries to retrieve the secret value, behind-the-scenes the `secretsmanager` calls KMS to `decrypt` the secret value. So, you can rely on KMS API events to track the secret value access.

```
{
  "source": ["aws.kms"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["kms.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["Decrypt"],
    "userIdentity": {
      "invokedBy": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That rule looks to be working, i'm wondering if this rule will trigger from a Lambda or will it only be a user?

Comment: The mentioned rule works only when a user tries to access the secret value through `secretsmanager`(either from the AWS console or its API). However, if a lambda function tries to access the secret value, then the `userIdentity` section will certainly change. So, remove the `userIdentity` section from the event rule, and it will enable you to receive all the `decrypt` events that occur in your account. Subsequently, based on the received events, you can adjust the mentioned event rule.

Comment: awesome, thanks for your explaination - i would pretty much still be lost without your knowledge.

Comment: Does this require read events enabled? I tried removing the `userIdentity` portion and it's not alerting on this at all.

Comment: Note that you need cloudtrail read events enabled in order to trigger this rule even if you set `--status "ENABLED_WITH_ALL_CLOUDTRAIL_MANAGEMENT_EVENTS"` on the `aws events put-rule`